# Вывод фраз "По рейтингу"

Tags: php, html

Есть код. Как его изменить, чтобы получился Вывод фраз "По рейтингу"?

```
<?php
//имя сервера
$serverMySql = "localhost";
// логин

$db_log  = "*******";
// пароль
$db_pass = "*****";
function db_connect($serverMySql, $db_log, $db_pass) //create connection
{
    $r = mysql_connect($serverMySql, $db_log, $db_pass);
    return $r;
}
//база данных
$database = "perecc";

//название таблицы в базе
$table = "article";

//кол-во пользователей на странице
$users_on_page = "100";

//подключаемся
db_connect($serverMySql, $db_log, $db_pass);
mysql_select_db($database);
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
// страницы
if (empty($_GET["p"])) {
    $_GET["p"] = "1";
}
$p = $_GET["p"];

// защита от ввода  
if (preg_match("/[%a-z_@.,^=:;Р°-СЏ\"*()&$#в„–+\-!?<>\~`|[{}\]]/i", $p)) {
    die(header("Location:sluch_list.php"));
}

// формируем запрос
$count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `id` from `$table`"));

// считаем страницы
$total = ceil($count / $users_on_page);
if ($p > $total) {
    $p = $total;
}

// формируем запрос
$first  = $p * $users_on_page - $users_on_page;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$table` LIMIT $first, $users_on_page");
?>
<?php
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) // цикл вывода
    {
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    print "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    print "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    print "</tr>";
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td>$data[0]</td>";
    print "<td>$data[2]</td>";
    print "<td>$data[1]</td>";
    print "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Рейтинг у меня в БД в другой таблице `rating_post`, колонка up (или по счету $data[1])

Фразы: Таблица article

```
{id} _ _{timestamp}     {content}        {author}
{21}___{2012-10-20}_ {Сейчас котам...} {«Автор»}
Рейтинг: Таблица rating_post
{id_post} {up} {down}
{21} _   _ {2}__{0}
```

Comment: Вместо вот этого бреда:

    if (empty($_GET["p"])) {
        $_GET["p"] = "1";
    }
    $p = $_GET["p"];
    if (preg_match("/[%a-z_@.,^=:;Р°-СЏ\"*()&$#в„–+\-!?<>\~`|[{}\]]/i", $p)) {
        die(header("Location:sluch_list.php"));
    }

надо использовать вот это:

    $p = intval(isset($_GET['p'])?$_GET['p']:1);

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `$table` AS tb
LEFT JOIN rating_post AS rp ON (tb.id = rp.id_post) 
ORDER BY rp.up 
LIMIT $first, $users_on_page"
```

Проверить не на чём, но может быть так?

Comment: Только не простой сортировкой по `up` (т.е. не `ORDER BY up`), это даст совсем плохой результат. Обычно рекомендуют сортировать по [нижней границе доверительного интервала по методу Вильсона](http://habrahabr.ru/company/darudar/blog/143188/) — в статье есть практически готовый SQL-запрос (где длинная формула и таблица `widgets`). Подробнее про матаппарат есть [на английской Википедии](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval).